# Elasticsearch: update by query: how to handle version conflict?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to execute update by query on elastic, when other daemons are (maybe) also updating documents. The consequence of this is version conflict.

I want to get list of **all**(not only one bulk) ids of conflicted documents (for manual retry) or set up retry_on_conflict for update by query.

How can I do it?

Example of my query:

```json
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source['msp']=null",
        "lang": "painless"
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "terms": {
                    "msp-rev": [44]
                }
            },
            "must" : {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "msp"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of the many writes that happen , does the last write win ? Is it from an application that this write happens ?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Use `update_by_query` with `conflicts=proceed`. This will not abort your update. In the response you will have an array `failures` from which all the id that failed are.

```json
POST /<index>/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source['msp']=null",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "terms": {
                "msp-rev": [44]
            }
        },
        "must" : {
            "exists": {
                "field": "msp"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Manually use the [update query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) to update the documents one by one.

```json
POST /<index>/_update/<_id>?retry_on_conflict=<some value>
{
  "doc": {
    "msp": null
  }
}
```

Comment: The "proceed" option indeed makes the request not get aborted when one conflict occurs but from my own experience the conflicted nodes do not appear in the "failures" field, if it did it would be relatively easy to set up a custom retry on conflict mechanism but I really don't think it is the case. I am using the latest version of Elasticsearch and I think this is the behavior, let me know if I am mistaken or if it does happen as you say in other versions.

Comment: Ah ! indeed ... seems like this is how it works ... I must have gotten confused with the documentation.

Comment: If you take the documentation to heart it does seem like the node ids should be int he failures field so in my opinion the confusion is definitely warranted. Maybe it's a bug on their part or something that we should ask as a feature because it would cover a serious caveat of the update by query request.